# Firebase records that flexibly reference other records

Tags: firebase

I'd like to create firebase collections with records that flexibly reference one another. More specifically, I'd like documents to be able to reference multiple documents across collections.

Here is made up example:

1. There is collection of people with various fields that properties stored in a document(e.g. {name: Mary, gender: Female, age: 23}, {name: Jim, gender: Male, age: 27}, etc).

2)There is a second collection music clubs that store properties various fields (e.g. {name: Jazz Club, address: 27 oak lane, number of members: 23}, {name: Death Metal, address: 112 ruby road, number of members: 52} ).

I want to link people to the clubs. E.g. Mary is in both Jazz and Metal. Jim is only a member of Jazz.

How would people suggest I connect to the people to the clubs? The two ways I can think of is to store list in either the people or club documents. So the "Mary" document would contains a list of (club) firebase document references to the clubs she is a member (Jazz and Metal). OR, clubs would have a list of firebase document references of all their members. So the Jazz Club document would have a list of firebase document references to Mary and Jim.

My understanding is firebase doesn't work well with lists. So how would one solve this?

Thanks

Comment: `What have you tried? This is not to tell you that your question is bad (it's actually quite interesting), but Stack Overflow is not a "code for me" place. Please show what you have tried.`

Comment: Thanks. I figured I’d just ask the question in the abstract before I hacked my way into a corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Store user UIDs who are a member of a particular club in it's document like:

```
{
  "clubID": "123",
  "name": "Music",
  "members": ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"]
}
```

To get a list of clubs of a specific user:

```
const userClubs = clubsRef.where('members', 'array-contains', 'userUID').get();
```

**Option 2:**

Store club IDs in each user's document like:

```
{
  "userUID": "y123",
  "name": "TestUser",
  "clubs": ["clubID1", "clubID2"]
}
```

This way you know know all the clubs of a specific user. But to get list of all users in a specific club, use the same logic as in option 1.

```
const clubMembers = usersRef.where('clubs', 'array-contains', 'clubID').get();
```

Though this could be an issue if your member can join thousands of clubs as Firestore document can contain a maximum of 1 MB data. In the case I'd just create a new collection containing membership documents (each membership doc storing userID, clubID, and any metadata) so I can query using either of those fields.

Comment: Thanks! That’s kinds what I was thinking but didn’t know that I search the array, which makes this super useful!